# linePlusBarChart in NVD3, rCharts and shiny

Tags: java, r, nvd3.js, shiny, rcharts

There exists an `NVD3` chart for combining a line and bar chart, `linePlusBarChart`. This would suit my data very well. However, it does not seem to be supported natively with `rCharts`. As far as I can see, the `NVD3` charts which are implemented in `rCharts` are (from [examples](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/nvd3/examples.R)):

- `scatterChart`
- `multiBarChart`
- `multiBarHorizontalChart`
- `pieChart`
- `lineChart`
- `lineWithFocusChart`
- `stackedAreaChart`

Is it possible to get other ones to work? It may be that I have misunderstood the structure of `rCharts+NVD3`! I'm quite new to Java, so I would be very grateful for good references, documentation, and general help!

But my basic and immediate question is: How to get a `linePlusBarChart` from `rCharts`? Or a way to layer a `lineChart` onto a bar chart?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not currently supported in rCharts. You can file a feature request on the github repo for rCharts and we can add it to our to-do-list.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm currently working on making it happen with `xCharts`, which seems marginally simpler than `NVD3`. I've made it work by manually adding the (data) dataset to the chart object and setting a new chart type.

Comment: I am currently able to do that using HighCharts (hPlot) and MorrisCharts (mPlot), they seem to have functions like layer and series which enable combining multiple type of graphs. If you find out how to do it using nPlot please let me also know.